# Gargos, Vicious Watcher Ruling - M20

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Gargos, Vicious Watcher (GVW) has the ability, "Whenever a creature you control becomes the target of a spell, Gargos, Vicious Watcher fights up to one target creature you don't control."

Next, an opponent targets GVW with a Pacifism Enchantment.  GVW may fight an opposition creature.  GVW is enchatned.

Next, Natural End is played to destroy the Pacifism Enchantment. Which scenario below is correct?

1) Does the Natural End target GVW, the Enchanted creature, triggering the ability to fight an opponent creature?

2) Does the Natural End target the Pacifism only, and GVW ability is not triggered - no fight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Natural End reads

> Destroy target artifact or enchantment. You gain 3 life.

Pacifism is the target, as the enchantment. Even though the spell is targeting an enchantment that is attached to Gargos, the enchantment itself is still the target, as per the wording.